# How to programmatically determine if Buefy input fields have error?

Tags: vuejs2, buefy

I am working on Buefy input fields and looking for a method that can tell me if there is any error on any of the form fields. [Buefy Input Documentation](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/input)

```
<b-field horizontal label="Title">
  <b-input
    v-model="model.title"
    name="title"
    type="text"
    minlength="10"
    required>
  </b-input>
</b-field>

<b-field horizontal label="Description">
  <b-input
    v-model="model.description"
    name="description"
    type="textarea">
  </b-input>
</b-field>
```

If there is no method available then how can we write our custom method to determine it. It will help to disable the submit method etc and much more in other use cases.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score -3):

There is now an extension now flagging the input missing /invalid. https://buefy.org/extensions/veevalidate/

Otherwise, custom validation should be made on Vue.js side, on Vue component methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, that extension is more headache than anything else.